# Multiple routes from router advertisements

Tags: cisco, router, ipv6, ping, icmpv6

Consider the following simplified setup:

[image]

- All devices are IPv6 enabled.
- Interfaces are configured in a way that we have 3 networks as shown.
- Router advertisments are enabled on both routers R1 & R2.

Because of router advertisemsents, SW2 has now two gateways to ::/0 networks.
So when I ping SW1 from SW2, everything is okay. However, when I ping SW3 from SW2, it's unreachable.

When I check in the wireshark, I find that SW2 **contacts only R1** for outside networks, even if these networks are unreachble.

I'm okay that SW2 contacts R1 first. ***But shouldn't SW2 try to contact R2 when R1 gives destination unreachable?***

I mean I would expect that when one router gives destination unreachable, the host should try to contact the **next gateway** for this network.

Comment: No. Only one gateway is used at a time. If one router loses access to the Internet it should withdraw its route and no longer advertise that it has a default gateway.

Comment: switches aren't routers.......